# How to wrap text inside a div in a custom form (ie. a circle) dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website for a school and I have made the blog post items round. My Problem is, that because they are round there is lots of room that can't be taken up with this. I was wondering if there was a way to set a different width to each line or activate some type of wrap feature to fill up the curves. What I want to achieve is make the p or text tags round to fill up the unused space in the post. Just as a note the blog is round by using the border radius feature in CSS.

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 730px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
}
.body {
    width: 655px;
    background: #06C;
    height: 144px;
    border-top-left-radius: 75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 75px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-right: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.image {
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    background: #0C3;
    margin-top: -150px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    border-radius: 75px;
    float: right;
}
.image img {
    border-radius: 75px;
    width: 144px;
    heiht: 144px;
}
.body p {
    width: 535px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non nisi vehicula, sodales mi vitae, ornare mi. Cras non urna ac lorem luctus consectetur eu et lacus. Nunc eget auctor sem. Donec sit amet libero condimentum mauris sodales eleifend. Fusce vitae eleifend tortor. Nullam dapibus orci non ipsum sodales tristique. Mauris pharetra sem ac velit pellentesque dignissim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum tristique dignissim tristique.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: First : Share some code, or better, make a fiddle...

Comment: @TheLittlePig what do you mean by a fiddle

Comment: for exemple : jsfiddle.net

Comment: afaik this is impossible - i'd be very interested in any solution you or anybody else would come up with.

Comment: Maybe http://www.csstextwrap.com/ can help

Comment: @enapupe that is a good idea but the thing is teachers need to be able to edit this. The way it is planned to be is all the code in php files and include it with the main html file and just have all their content on the first file

Comment: @KesaVan what works fine? the fiddle or the code?

Comment: you can help it overflow:auto; ?

Comment: hi @LogicBurner could you please give me some more information on the Pre tag because it just made the text in a long line :(

Comment: If you write anything inside <pre> It will print as the same with same space and line breaks

Comment: Since this is not (yet) doable with purely CSS, I tried to go the Javascript way (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With current browser support, this is not possible in CSS only, so we need to use Javascript (I also used jQuery for simplicity) here:

```
for(var x=-4;x<5;x++) {
    $('.body').prepend('<div class="float" style="width:'+(x*x*2.5)+'px"></div>');   
}
```

This will insert a couple of floating `div` elements that push your text in the shape of a half-circle. Along with this CSS:

```
.float {
    float:left;
    height: 11%;
    clear:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

You get something that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4n5pA/3/

Comment: Why was this votedown? I liked it.. It has simplicity in its complication. +1

Comment: Don't know, maybe someone was having a bad day. ;) Thanks, enapupe! Though I have to admit, the question isn't formulated very clearly. I'll try to improve it...

Comment: Hi @S.B. I finally got it working from your code! Thankyou soooo much!